# Is it a mandatory to have two classes(Node,Tree) while implementing a binary tree?

Tags: python, class, object, data-structures, binary-tree

This may sound silly but trust me , I have searched for various articles online and could not find a proper explanation or no explanation at all ,  Does it really need two classes one for Node and one for tree to implement binary tree? for Instance , let's take a simple python code :

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        

class BinaryTree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
```

this is bascially which I have seen in many online articles , and recently I started working on AlgoExpert course where there was a question about a function which takes Binary tree as Input and an target value as another input and gets the closest value to the target value in tree and return it.

the piece of code given as :

```
 #This is the class of the input root. Do not edit it.
    class BinaryTree:
        def __init__(self, data):
            self.data = data
            self.left = None
            self.right = None
```

Now I am totally confused looking at this snippet , how can I work with just one class ?
I am trying to get the concept here , this could sound silly to some people but I would rather ask this question than regret not asking at all. Any input is appreciated .

Comment: My first thought is that any node in the tree can be interpreted as a representation of its entire subtree beneath. Hence no need for a separate class for such simple implementation.

Comment: If you have separate Tree/Node classes, then the Tree object can maintain its identity no matter what changes are made to the contents - including having no Nodes at all, or some operation that changes which Node is the root of the tree.  With only a single class, you can only conveniently handle operations that don't change the root - but that's often all you need for a specific application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use only one class to implement a tree, e.g., `Node` class in the first snippet you present is sufficient.

That being said, if you have only one class, you would have to always keep an object referring to the root node, so you can access the tree.

The class `BinaryTree` (in the first snippet) could help to do that, but it is not necessary.

Example code using `BinaryTree` from the second snippet and declaring a tree:

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None



def main():
    root = BinaryTree(1)
    root.left = BinaryTree(2)
    root.right = BinaryTree(3)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* implement a tree with only a single class, but it will have a much more limited API than you could implement with two separate classes. There are a number of situations where having a separate container object makes a lot more sense, and a single-class implementation will need its users to handle special cases.

For example, an empty tree is easy to represent with two separate classes. It would be an instance of the `Tree` class with its `head` reference, which normally points to a `Node` instance, pointing to `None` instead. All the `Tree` methods would know how to handle that case, so the user wouldn't need to do anything special.

To represent an empty tree with only one class, you'd just have a reference to `None`, since there is no root node to point to. That can be inconvenient, since you won't be able to call any `Tree` related methods on it. Any situation where you try to refer to the root node will need to have special logic to handle the empty-tree case.

But sometimes you don't need a fancy API, just a very basic one will do for the limited use you're making of the data structure. In that case, handling a trivial special case isn't that much of a burden. Writing an extra class might be more work.

Answer (score 0):

No, you just need the node class. Your whole tree is then referenced via the root node. Mathematically speaking any subtree of your tree is also a tree, even if you just have one node, it would be a leaf and the root of that subtree at the same time.

If you want to be even more simplistic take a look at [heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)), they are implemented via an array.